# Multiple materials with different textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Just started getting some fun from Blender and currently stuck deeply with materials.

I am trying to create a mesh with different materials, each having its own texture, applied to different parts of the mesh.

What I have done is:

1. a couple of `UV maps`
2. a couple of `textures` (for each UV Map)
3. a couple of materials (for each texture)

Currently I am using Blender renderer.

The problem I am facing is that only one material is displayed in a `Material` display mode and for only one submesh. Yet, when I switch to `Texture` display mode - I can see all the textures, assigned correctly.

**UPD:** here is what I mean saying *Material display mode*:

[image]

[image: Material mode]
[image: Texture mode]

How to fix that? Or should I use Cycles with its nodes?

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: I've done this with the Cycles Render Engine, and have't had this issue. But, the textures I was using were only used to color the materials. I don't know what will happen if you use normal map or bump map textures.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you mean. From the screenshot it looks like you have several meshes, one for each texture. What is "material display mode"? You can have different textures applied to the same mesh without splitting the mesh up like you have done. I think that might be what you need to do if you want them to show up all at once. Like this.

[image]

Edit: To explain a little better. Here The red material has no textures, the green material has one texture (cloud) and the blue material has two textures (cloud and noise) Hope that helps.
[image]

Comment: Sure, I want to have a couple of materials with different textures for each part of my model.

Comment: Yet, I do not know how to do this - I event split my model to submeshes, but no effect...

Comment: Just select the faces you want to apply the material to in edit mode, then click assign in the material tab. See how there is a an "x" and a "+" right next to the material or texture? Just click "+" to add more, "x" to remove them. Then with the texture selected go to the material tab and do the same thing. + to add as many materials as you like to each texture.